# How to have a two line header in my knitted html in rstudio

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I want to limit my character length in r studio and I have a long header for one of my topics. I want the header divided into two lines but still shows in html after knitted as a header.

My title is: `Animals in the region are getting declawed and slain.`

on r studio it's currently like this:

> ## Animals in the region are getting \
>
> declawed and slain.

My problem is that in html it shows "Animals in the region are getting" as the header "and declawed and slain." as normal text.

How do I solve this please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<br>` tags to denote new lines for html output. Just a note that it is good practice to provide some reproducible code when asking a question as this makes it easier for people to answer.

```
---
title: "Animals in the region are getting <br> declawed and slain."
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

### Animals in the region are getting <br> declawed and slain.
```

Comment: It's not a title. I was asking for a heading

Comment: It's exactly the same principle anywhere - see updated answer.